# What do you call an object inserted between two pieces (of bone)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, medical

Imagine someone has a broken bone and after removing any slivers there is a void between the two bone fragments. In order to assure that the bone grows back correctly, a *piece* is inserted between the two ends. The piece is not attached to the bone parts, which are held together through a plate. Rather it fills up the space in-between the parts to alleviate pressure on the plate and screws. I am looking for a word to describe this piece.

My first thought was *wedge* but the object in question is more cylinder-shaped than wedge-shaped. I went on to think of words ending on *filler*, but I have so far found no satisfactory word. Which word best describes the piece in question?

Comment: In situations like that, the pieces of bone might be pinned together, in which case you'd call the thing connecting them a pin.

Comment: @Nicole I added some more text to describe the function of the piece better

Comment: If "the piece" is biological, it's a "graft".  If it's something artificial, you could call it a "bridge" or a "matrix".

Comment: [It is now thought to be better in fact to leave the ends separated by a small gap, for example a millimeter or less, which will eventually be bridged by new bone growth.](http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US5298115) That's from a patent application re *production of **prostheses** such as are used in orthopaedic and trauma surgery for pinning broken bones*.

Comment: I'd go with ***shim***.

Comment: Try clicking on the links e.g fig 16.2. (in blue) to see the enlarged images. Maybe I'm completely off, but think of it as a way of eliminating possible contenders. http://cmapspublic.ihmc.us/rid=1M7KSG44M-24BTR5G-2CT6Y/Methods%20of%20internal%20fixation.pdf You need someone who's an expert in orthopedics.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a very precise medical term for this but, until that is found,  you could use [*support*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/support?s=t) (definition from the Free Online Dictionary):

> 12. something that serves as a foundation, prop, brace, or stay.

Answer (score 3):

***implant, wedge-implant assembly, prosthesis, graft***

> Biocompatibility of implant metals in bone tissue culture - Page v
>   Ljilja Golijanin - 1988
>
> The second was to grow bone on three **implant metals** (pure titanium,
>   titanium alloy, and cobalt- chromium alloy) to see whether the metals
>   were biocompatible and therefore would **support the growth of bone**.
>
> -
>
> Spinal Instrumentation: Surgical Techniques - Page 678 Daniel H. Kim,
>   ‎Alexander R. Vaccaro, ‎Richard Glenn Fessler - 2011 -
>
> After **screw** or **hook** insertion, a **titanium rod** is snapped into the
>   **wedge-implant assembly**, providing a simple, easy, and fast ...
>   scoliosis and scoliosis with deficient posterior element such as that
>   resulting from laminectomy • Spinal fractures (acute reduction or
>   later ... Osteoporosis: Decreased bone mass in osteoporosis patients
>   will mean less secure purchase of fixation, particularly screws, in
>   the spine.

The author should search Google Books for say:

[**bone "wedge implant" fracture**](https://www.google.com/search?q=bone%20implant%20fracture&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=bone%20%22wedge%20implant%22%20fracture)

**bone  implant fracture**

etc.

Comment: In this case I think implant would be too generic as it does not say anything about the function, no?

Answer (score 2):

[image][image]

You must be talking about [**"bone cement"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_cement).

> - Bone cements have been used very successfully to anchor artificial joints (hip joints, knee joints, shoulder and elbow joints) for more than half a century. Artificial joints (referred to as prostheses) are anchored with bone cement. The bone cement fills the free space between the prosthesis and the bone and plays the important role of an elastic zone. This is necessary because the human hip is acted on by approximately 10-12 times the body weight and therefore the bone cement must absorb the forces acting on the hips to ensure that the artificial implant remains in place over the long term.
>     Bone cement chemically is nothing more than Plexiglas (i.e. polymethyl methacrylate or PMMA). PMMA was used clinically for the first time in the 1940s in plastic surgery to close gaps in the skull.

Comment: Now, I'd be inclined to say this is the right answer, but the OP speaks about a *piece*, and not material. This *cement* solidifies, right? Maybe an image would help?

Comment: But if you have to fill a space left by a prosthesis, it's got to be something that adapts to it.  In addition to prostheses, this is what orthopedists use.

Comment: It's **inserted** between two pieces of bone, maybe like a screw? Is the cement then taken out? Perhaps it then looks like a cylinder. Excuse my extreme ignorance on the subject.

Comment: [cancellous bone screw](https://www2.aofoundation.org/wps/portal/!ut/p/a0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOKN_A0M3D2DDbz9_UMMDRyDXQ3dw9wMDAx8jfULsh0VAdAsNSU!/?bone=Femur&segment=Proximal&soloState=lyteframe&contentUrl=srg/popup/further_reading/PFxM2/31/661_32-Neck_fxs_surg_treat.jsp) Maybe?

Comment: I've seen your link.  That's a type of screw.

Comment: Re-reading the OP's description and your post, this answer fits (excuse the pun).

Answer (score 0):

How about calling it an "insert".
(shim wasn't bad either)